# How to refresh div with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I know there are many entries about this topic but I dont get my code to work.
I build a div container (this is the div I want to refresh every second) which includes 3 other div containers.

My code so far:
index.php

```
<div id="ajax">
   <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="showPGF"> 
         <?php
            $controller->getEntries();
         ?>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="showNGi_sample"> 
         <?php
            $controller->getUsers();
         ?>
      </div>
   </div>

   <br>

   <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="showNGi_sample"> 
         <?php
            $controller->getPGFEntries();
         ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function ajax(){
        $('#ajax').load('index.php',function() {
            $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }

    ajax(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        ajax() // this will run after every 1 seconds
    }, 1000);

}
```

I want to get the DIV with the "ajax" id to get reload every second. Because I want to get always the current Entries/Users from my database (execute the php call every second). But currently it dont refresh and I need to press F5 to get the new entries shown.

Comment: What’s the purpose of the `unwrap` call inside the callback function? `$(this)` in that location, probably isn’t what you think it was. I’m guessing what you actually want here, is to simply use the syntax for [Loading Page Fragments](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) ...?

Comment: Just use `$('#ajax').load('index.php #ajax'`)` - no callback needed.

Comment: *"But currently it dont[sic] refresh"* - please tell us what is *is* doing.  Is it calling `ajax()`?  Is it loading `index.php` from the server?  What's the content of index.php each time (check the network tab on the browser) - is it loading a **cached** version of index.php each time? (will tell you in the brower network tab)  is it loading fresh data each time but not updating the the UI?   There's **so much more** you can (and need to) tell us than "it don't[sic] refresh"

Comment: @freedomn-m I changed it to //$(this).unwrap(); but it still dont work.

Comment: @freedomn-m my Index includes some PHP-Calls to get datas from my database. I want to refresh the divs to make a new php call to get current datas from my database. It dont work because I create new datas in my database and the div dont refresh, so I cant see them.

Comment: The problem is there are multiple components - you're only looking at the final result and assuming the whole thing isn't working - you need to look deeper to find which part isn't working.  It could be any or all of index.php / the ajax call / the settimeout (unlikely) / the part that loads the (otherwise working) data onto the page.  Or you simply haven't included jquery.  "not working" is not enough information.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your answers. I understand you, my problem is that I cant handle with JS/JQuery/AJAX. Im not a programmer, Im a noob who try to code. I would give you detaliled answers/problems but I dont know how to find/analyse it. I just tryed to get the div reloaded (without page reload) to get all datas displayed. Im sorry :I

Comment: You should not use `setInterval()` with asynchrounous functions like `load()`. You will sooner or later run into problems, especially with such a short interval. Your last call might not have finished and the next call will already get triggered

Comment: @Lapskaus Do you have a solution code for me which dont run into the problem? It can be also reaload every 2 seconds.

Comment: To avoid this, use `setTimeout()` in the callback of your load() function. That way the next call will only get triggered when the last call has finished. I dont think that this will solve your problem entirely though.

Comment: You are also calling the `ajax()` function inside of itself. This will cause a callstack overflow, so to speak, and crash your app.